# Migrate content of CCK fields

Tags: 7, entities, migrations

I need to transfer the content of a specific content type with CCK fields from Drupal 5 to Drupal 7.

What's the best and easiest and fastest way to do so?

Comment: check this http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/1420/migration-from-drupal-5-to-7

Comment: direct approach http://quicksketch.org/node/5739

Comment: thanks for the links but I dont intend to upgrade drupal 5 to 7, I just want the content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once I had a same problem and after couple of hours testing/working with couple of approaches I figured out that the best way to deal with this is using [views bonus pack](https://drupal.org/project/views_bonus%E2%80%8E) module to get a CSV export file:

> This group of modules is sort of a recipe module that makes things
>   easier by showing how to integrate some other modules as well as
>   providing miscellaneous features that aren't distributed by Views
>   itself. Sometimes these modules are only base recipes that will need
>   to be themed and spiced up to fit your needs so be creative!

and import it via [feeds](https://drupal.org/project/feeds%E2%80%8E) module:

> Import or aggregate data as nodes, users, taxonomy terms or simple
>   database records.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [Migrate](https://drupal.org/project/migrate) module.

> The migrate module provides a flexible framework for migrating content
>   into Drupal from other sources (e.g., when converting a web site from
>   another CMS to Drupal). Out-of-the-box, support for creating core
>   Drupal objects such as nodes, users, files, terms, and comments are
>   included - it can easily be extended for migrating other kinds of
>   content. Content is imported and rolled back using a bundled web
>   interface (Migrate UI module) or included Drush commands

check out the other modules as given in 
[LINK](http://www.wunderkraut.com/blog/migrating-content-from-drupal-5-to-drupal-6/2010-10-19)

Node import
Backup and migrate
Table wizard + Migrate

...

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I made a mistake, my drupal is 5, and I want to migrate from that to 7.

Comment: pls check updated answer and link

Comment: I checked the link you mentioned, it seems quite a workaround and mostly suitable for D6 to D7

Comment: It's goin to need some programming language skills to get it done via Migrate for D5 and since it doesnt have a D5 version I'm not sure if it's the best approach